# Quick.db discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quick.db

I'm making a userinfo command that returns items from a .db file but it returns as **[object Object]**. How do i make it so it returns the names?
heres my code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`)
const db = require(`quick.db`);

exports.execute = async(client, message, args) => {
    let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
    let hasStarted = db.fetch(`started_${member.id}`)
    let bal = db.fetch(`money_${member.id}`)
    let items = db.get(`items_${member.id}`)
    let displayItems;
    let started;

    if (bal === null) bal = 0;
    if (items === null) {
        displayItems = 'This user has no items!';
    } else {
        displayItems = items;
    }
    if (hasStarted === null) {
        started = 'False'
    } else {
        started = 'True'
    }

    const userEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(member.displayName + '#' + member.user.discriminator + "'s Profile")
    .addField(`Balance:`, bal)
    .addField(`Items:`, displayItems)
    .addField(`Has Started:`, started)
    .setFooter(`Requested By: ${message.author.username}`, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
    .setImage(member.user.avatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
    message.channel.send(userEmbed)
}

exports.help = {
    name: 'userinfo',
    aliases: ['user'],
    usage: 'userinfo <user>'
}
```

Comment: when `[object Object]` gets displayed, it means that the thing you are trying to display is an object. Try to `console.log()` to see what is in that object.

Comment: Quick.db is a promise based node package. When something is promise based it usually means you have to await for them. Remembering that you can only await items in an async function.

Answer (score 0):

Discord doesn't send objects, but strings. If the data is an Object, you should try:

```js
// Send this, not object:
c.send(JSON.stringify(object)) // Also, you should wrap in a code block with the JSON language, it'll look much nicer
```

If it's a Promise, you should try:

```js
c.send(await promise)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
let hasStarted = db.fetch(`started_${member.id}`)
let bal = db.fetch(`money_${member.id}`)
let items = db.get(`items_${member.id}`)
let displayItems;
let started;

if (bal === null) bal = 0;
if (items === null) {
    displayItems = 'This user has no items!';
} else {
    displayItems = items;
}
if (hasStarted === null) {
    started = 'False'
} else {
    started = 'True'
}

const userEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(member.displayName + '#' + member.user.discriminator + "'s Profile")
.addField(`Balance:`, `${bal}`)
.addField(`Items:`, `${displayItems}`)
.addField(`Has Started:`, `${started}`)
.setFooter(`Requested By: ${message.author.username}`, message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
.setImage(member.user.avatarURL({ dynamic:true }))
message.channel.send({embeds: [userEmbed}})
```

Comment: Consider adding more of a description to what the code does and how it addresses the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).